# Is .onAppear causing text to disappear in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm making a simple countdown. What I expect to happen is `First` counts to `0`, then `Second` counts to `0`. When the statement switches to the else block, the HStack text disappears in the canvas. Why could that be happening?

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestCountdown: View {
    @State var first = 5
    @State var second = 5
    @State var totalDuration = 30
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
             Text("\(totalDuration)")
            if (first > 0) && (second > 0) {
                HStack {
                    TestCode(number: $first, title: "First")
                    Spacer()
                    TestCode(number: $second, title: "Second")
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
                if self.totalDuration > 0 {
                    self.totalDuration -= 1
                    
                    if self.first > 0 {
                        self.first -= 1
                    } else {
                        self.second -= 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestCode: View {
    @Binding var number: Int
    @State var title: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
            Text("\(number)")
                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 50, maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means your `HStack` will be shown when **both** `first` and `second` are > 0:

```
if (first > 0) && (second > 0) {
    HStack {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you want to display `HStack` when **either** of them are > 0 you can do:

```
if first > 0 || second > 0 { ... }
```

See Apple documentation:

- [BasicOperators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html)